# What is different between "<<-EOF" and "<<EOF" in bash script?

Tags: bash, here-document

I did google this topic and all results are talking about `<<EOF`.
But I saw scripts using `<<-EOF`, but I can not find anywehre by googling.
Thus, What is different between `<<-EOF` and `<<EOF` in bash script?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) in the bash manual

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`<<-EOF` will ignore leading tabs in your heredoc, while `<<EOF` will not. Thus:

```
cat <<EOF
    Line 1
    Line 2
EOF
```

will produce

```
    Line 1
    Line 2
```

while

```
cat <<-EOF
    Line 1
    Line 2
EOF
```

produces

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `<<-EOF`, I recommend the man page of the Bourne Shell:

If, however, the hyphen (-) is appended to <<:

1. leading tabs are stripped from word before the shell input is read (but after parameter and command substitution is done on word);
2. leading tabs are stripped from the shell input as it is read and before each line is  compared  with  word; and
3. shell input is read up to the first line that literally matches the resulting word, or to an EOF.

So `<<-` allows to indent the content of the here document for better readability.